# Is it possible to globally replace `require` in Node?

Tags: node.js

If I want to make a function that intercepts all `require` calls in the entire Node process (even those made from dependencies), is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine the require function on the global object at the start of the process like so:

```
global.require = function(...) {};
```

Comment: As of NodeJS v7.2.0, this appears not to be working.